# Is there a quadratic equation for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations

If you have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ that satisfies

$$aA^2 + bA + cI_n = \mathbf{0}_n$$

does it let you say anything about $A$?

---

I'm thinking:

- If $a= 0$ then then $A$ must be a diagonal matrix, in particular it is a multiple of the identity matrix: $$A = (-c/b)I_n$$
- If $b=0$ then there can be infinitely many solutions for $A$, one of them is a multiple of the identity matrix: $$A = \pm\left(\sqrt{-c/a}\,\right)I_n$$ but I think these are [not the only solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Examples) in that case.

Can anything more general be said about quadratic equation in matrices?

Comment: there could be more than two square roots of a matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If a matrix satisfies a polynomial, it implies that all its [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) satisfy this same polynomial. (For example in your situation, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $aA^2v + bAv + cI_nv = (a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c)v=0$, and since $v$ is nonzero this implies that $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$.

In particular, you know that $A$ has at most two eigenvalues, and in particular they could be either of the roots of the polynomial $aX^2+bX+c$. (If it happens that this polynomial has only one root, then you know $A$ has only one eigenvalue.)

Using the [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), it tells you that $A$'s Jordan form has only at most these two values on the diagonal; thus $A$ is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to a Jordan form matrix with at most those two values on the diagonal.

Actually, you can know a little more. If the quadratic polynomial $aX^2+bX+c$ has two distinct roots, then the matrix must be [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix). Indeed, a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) of size $m\times m$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$ has [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) $(X-\alpha)^m$, and your matrix can't satisfy a polynomial one of its Jordan blocks doesn't satisfy, so if your polynomial has the form $a(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$ with $\alpha\neq \beta$, then it cannot have a jordan block of size $m>1$. So all the Jordan blocks are size 1. To summarize, if your polynomial has 2 distinct roots, then $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with at most those 2 values on the diagonal.

If your polynomial has a double root, i.e., it's of the form $a(X-\alpha)^2$, then its Jordan form can have blocks of size up to 2. So in this case, it's similar to a Jordan matrix with only one value on the diagonal and blocks of size 1 and/or 2.

This is the most you can say though. Any matrix like I have described will be satisfy your polynomial, because all its Jordan blocks do.